# How to write multi lines in one Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editing

I want to write multi-lines in one MS Excel cell.

But whenever I press the *`Enter`* key, the cell editing ends and the cursor moves to next cell. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

What you want to do is to **wrap the text** in the current cell. You can do this manually by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> every time you want a new line

Or, you can set this as the default behaviour by pressing the **Wrap Text** in the **Home** tab on the Ribbon. Now, whenever you hit enter, it will automatically wrap the text onto a new line rather than a new cell.

[image]

Comment: Not quite the same as the OP's question, but you can also wrap existing text by selecting the cells, and selectiing "Format Cells..." and then clicking the "Wrap Text" checkbox.

Comment: For those of you who are software developers and confused by all the talk about "wrap the text" and "why would 'word wrapping' need to be enabled"... in Excel... if you want to have a more than one line of text... then "word wrapping" MUST be enabled. You can test this "feature" by inserting a new line via `alt` + `enter` then disabling "word wrapping" and see your new line character somehow disappears.

Comment: For those familiar with `libreoffice`, inserting new lines is done via `ctrl` + `enter` and does not require enabling "word wrapping" for a cell.

Comment: "Now, whenever you hit enter, it will automatically wrap the text onto a new line rather than a new cell." ... does this still work for anyone with the 2019 version of Excel?  When I turn on "Wrap Text" for the cells, pressing Enter is still going down to the next row.  I'm working on a spreadsheet where I'm always entering multiple lines of text, so would really love this to work.  Holding ALT every time is too cumbersome.

Answer (score 39):

You have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter a carriage return inside a cell.

Answer (score 39):

1. Edit a cell and type what you want on the first "row"
2. Press one of the following, depending on your OS:

   **Windows:** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   **Mac:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type what you want on the next "row" in the same cell
4. Repeat as needed.

Note that inserting carriage returns with the key combinations above produces different behavior than turning on `Wrap Text`. In the screenshot below, `column A` has the carriage returns and `column B` has `Wrap Text` turned on. Changing the width of a column with carriage returns doesn't remove them. Changing the width of a column with `Wrap Text` turned on will change where the lines break.

[image: In-cell line breaks in Excel]

Answer (score 17):

Use the combination <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> never worked for me.  I had to go to `Format Cells` and make sure that the `Number` tab was set to `Text`.  That allowed me to see exactly as I had input.  My issue could have been Mac specific though.

Comment: [Alt]+[Enter] is windows specific, the Mac specific code is in another answer